# VBA code to move cell selection to line above each time data is entered

Tags: excel, vba

Each time I enter data into cell A4 it gets entered down to A5. I need this to move right back to A4 or stay on A4 without ever moving. This needs to occur each time I enter data into A4. I can't find a way to make this work. Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub MoveUp()
'    MoveUp 
'
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "12345"
    Range("A5").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code that does the moving.

Comment: Sub MoveUp()
'
' MoveUp Macro
'

'
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "12345"
    Range("A5").Select
End Sub

Comment: Not in the comments, edit your original post to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line of your code which says

```
Range("A5").Select
```

---

I thought at first that you didn't actually have a macro doing the moving, you just wanted a way to stop Excel **automatically** selecting the cell below when you press Enter, which can easily be stopped by changing an option:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the worksheet code of the sheet on which you want the code to run:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A4")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Me.Range("A5").Value = Target.Value
    Target.Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```